# Sending scheduled email to participants before/after event

Tags: civirules

Maybe I'm missing something but I can't seem to find a way to send a scheduled email to participants of an event (f.i. 1 hour before or 1 hour after an event) using CiviRules.

Or maybe that's not possibile with CiviRules?

(the reason why I would like to use CiviRules for this is because i can use a specific emailaddress (location type) to send the email to the participant which is not possibile with the standard scheduled reminders)